# How to generate AES-ECB encryption secret key given examples of plaintexts and hashes?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, aes

My question is that, suppose you have some AES-ECB encrypted hash and you want to decode it. You are also given a bunch of example plaintexts and hashes. For example:

I want: unknown_plaintext for the hash given_hash
and i have a bunch of known_plaintexts and hashes that have been encrypted with the same secret key. None of them (obviously) are the exact same to the given hash.

Please let me know if you can help. This is not for malicious intents, just to learn how Cryptography and AES systems work.

Comment: It's a little unclear to me which operations you're doing in what order exactly. Is this correct: You have a list of plaintexts with the corresponding encrypted hashes. The plaintexts are first hashed and then the hash is encrypted with AES-ECB. You want to find the key with which the hashes have been encrypted.

Comment: @mschwaig yes. that is what i want.

Comment: @DaTechnoGuru Sorry but the cryptologists who develop encryption are not stupid, this is not possible.

Comment: If you want to know how encryption works try [Software Security](https://www.coursera.org/learn/software-security/home) by University of Maryland, College Park, it's free.

Comment: @zaph Don't you mean Crypto I by Stanford university? That makes more sense.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes No, I am aware of the Stanford course and Dan Boneh is excellent. Both courses get bogged down in math and proofs and the UofM course, because of its shortness, gets past them faster. Both courses will cause eyes to glaze over in the beginning and many to just give up.

Comment: @zaph Tried the Software Security two times already, ran out of time :( 1 August I'll try again - on company time :P. Before that I'll rewrite some more crypto related CERT, OWASP and CWE rules ...

Comment: What is missing are practical courses, how to use cryptography as most developer will. As an example I have searched for a textbook that explains how to properly handle passwords and have not found one. A course about best practices using AES, the different modes and how to make a choice. About CBC, padding errors and creating a padding oracle by accident. Look at the questions here on SO, they are not answered by either course nor any current textbook. Even "Software Security" by McGraw (2006) does not discuss handling passwords.

Comment: @zaph I was writing one, went the same way as the course... finished just the draft of the 1st 3 chapters :(

Comment: The problem with OWASP, which I link to often, is that it is on the Internet along with all kinds of other garbage and on the Internet everything is rather equal to those who are are not already knowledgable

Answer (score 1):

This is not computationally feasible. I.e., you can't do this.

Modern encryption algorithms like AES are resistant to [known-plaintext attacks,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) which is what you are describing.

There has been some past success in a category called a[daptive chosen plaintext attacks.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack) Often these exploit an ["oracle."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_attack) In this scenario, an attacker can decrypt a single message by repeatedly asking the victim whether it can successfully decrypt a guess generated by the attacker. By being smart about choosing successive guesses, the attacker could decrypt the message with a million tries or so, which is a relatively small number. But even in this scenario, the attacker can't recover the key.

As an aside, ciphers don't generate hashes. They output cipher text. Hash functions (aka message digests) generate hashes.

Answer (score 1):

For any respectable block cipher (and AES is a respectable block cipher), the only way to decrypt a ciphertext block (not "hash") is to know the key, and the only way to find the key from a bunch of plaintext-ciphertext pairs is by guessing a key and seeing if it maps a known plaintext onto the corresponding ciphertext.  If you have some knowledge of how the key was chosen (e.g., SHA-256 of a pet's name), this might work; but if the key was randomly selected from the set of all possible AES keys, the number of guesses required to produce a significant probability of success is such a large number that you wander off into age-of-the-universe handwaving.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that all the encrypted hashes are encrypted with the same key you can first try to find that key using your pairs of plaintexts and encrypted hashes. The most obvious way to do that would be to just take one of your plaintexts, first hash it and then try out all the possible keys to encrypt it until it matches the encrypted hash that you know. If the key you're looking for is just one of the many many possible AES keys **this is set to fail, because it would take way too long to try all the keys**.

Assuming you were able to recover the AES key somehow, you can decrypt that one hash you don't have a plaintext for and start looking for the plaintext.
The more you know about the plaintext, the easier this guesswork would be. You could just throw the decrypted hash into google and see what it spits out, query databases of known hashes or make guesses in the most eduated way possible. **This step will again fail, if the hash is strong enough and the plaintext is random enough.**

Answer (score 0):

As other people have indicated, modern encryption algorithms are specifically designed to resist this kind of attack. Even a rather weak encryption algorithm like the Tiny Encryption Algorithm would require well over 8 *million* chosen plaintexts to do anything like this. Better algorithms like AES, Blowfish, etc. require vastly more than that.

As of right now, there are no practical attacks on AES.

If you're interested in learning about cryptography, the older Data Encryption Standard (DES) may actually be a more interesting place to start than AES; there's a lot of literature available about it and it was already broken (the code to do so is still freely available online - studying it is actually really useful).